# Front Camera Crash when turning flash for custom camera?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift4, avcapturedevice

I tried to set up flash on/off for camera in the custom camera app , I am trying to make but the camera keeps crashing on switching on flash in front camera mode in iPhone 6. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
if ((currentCamera?.hasFlash)!) {
    do {
        _ = try currentCamera?.lockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print("aaaa")
    }

    if (currentCamera?.isTorchActive)! {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "flashOff"), for: .normal)
        currentCamera?.torchMode = AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.off
    } else {
        // sets the torch intensity to 100%
        do {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "flash"), for: .normal)
            _ = try currentCamera?.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
        } catch {
            print("bbb")
        }
        //    avDevice.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
    }
    // unlock your device
    currentCamera?.unlockForConfiguration()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without crushing log it tough to answer.

```
//this code works for me. 

if ([self.captureDevice isFlashAvailable]) {
    if (self.captureDevice.flashActive) {
        if([self.captureDevice lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
            self.captureDevice.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeOff;
            [sender setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
            [sender setSelected:NO];
        }
    }
    else {
        if([self.captureDevice lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
            self.captureDevice.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeOn;
            [sender setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
            [sender setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
    [self.captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: what happened when the crash occurred. I mean, is there any reason shows? or could you please debug line by line so that you can find out the line where crush is happening.